# Springboot API returning null value? How can I fix it?

Tags: spring-boot, api

[Postman not showing any results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpRZC.png)

Git hub link - https://github.com/Parthhsheth/Search

The code runs perfect on my system but it is not giving any output.
Simplying returning [{}] when I try to use the search function.

**Controller**:

```
package cpp.search.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import cpp.search.entity.Employee;
import cpp.search.service.EmployeeService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/Employees")
public class EmployeeController {

private EmployeeService employeeService;

public EmployeeController(EmployeeService employeeService) {
    super();
    this.employeeService = employeeService;
}

@GetMapping("/search")
public ResponseEntity<List<Employee>> searchEmployee(@RequestParam("query") String query){
    return ResponseEntity.ok(employeeService.searchEmployee(query));
}

@PostMapping
public Employee createEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
    return employeeService.createEmployee(employee);
}
}
```

**Service**:

```
package cpp.search.service;

import cpp.search.entity.Employee;

import java.util.List;

public interface EmployeeService {
List<Employee> searchEmployee(String query);

Employee createEmployee(Employee employee);
}
```

**Service.Impl**:

```
package cpp.search.service.impl;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import cpp.search.entity.Employee;
import cpp.search.repository.EmployeeRepository;
import cpp.search.service.EmployeeService;

@Service
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {

private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;


public EmployeeServiceImpl(EmployeeRepository employeeRepository) {
    super();
    this.employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
}

@Override
public List<Employee> searchEmployee(String query) {
    List<Employee> employees = 
employeeRepository.searchEmployee(query);
    return employees;
}
@Override 
public Employee createEmployee(Employee employee) {
    return employeeRepository.save(employee);
}

}
```

**Repository**

```
package cpp.search.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;

import cpp.search.entity.Employee;

public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {
@Query("SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE " +
        "e.firstName LIKE CONCAT('%', :query, '%')" +
        "Or e.lastName LIKE CONCAT('%', :query, '%')" +
        "Or e.id LIKE CONCAT('%', :query, '%')")
List<Employee> searchEmployee(String query);
}
```

**Employee.java**

```
package cpp.search.entity;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;


@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String firstName;
private String middleName;
private String lastName;
private boolean covid_result;

}
```

These are all the files.

It got linked with MySQL, since it created 'employee' table in the database.

But when I'm giving JSON data in Postman it is not working and no new rows are created in MySQL.

Also the search function is not working.

I inserted an entry manually in database and tried to search it via Postman(you can see in the picture). But it is not working.

**Edit**

**Screenshots after using h2**

[Adding employee](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpRZC.png)

[MySQL after adding employee](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PJCF.png)

[Manually adding a query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbeLp.png)

[Searching it using API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEBy2.png)

Comment: Can you please directly add the relevant code pieces and ask a specific question instead of asking something like 'How can I fix my program?'? Please take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Ausgefuchster Could you check the image? I myself am not sure what is causing that error, and I think it not even an error since everything is working fine, but not able to get an output.

Comment: Ofcourse I could click through the files on Github or even clone this but this would mean more work for me. And this is something you could easily do especially since you want our help.  Just provide the controller, service and repository methods and if you think something else is important to know add this aswell

Comment: @Ausgefuchster Alright, updated.

Answer (score 0):

The data you want to save probably does not get saved because you never flush the changes.
Just use `employeeRepository.saveAndFlush(employee);` instead of `employeeRepository.save(employee);` and your data should get saved.
But I have no idea why the GET isn't working since you don't get an error and everything looks fine. I recommend you test the query in a console to make sure it's working fine.

Comment: You mean to test my query in 'MySQL'? If yes, I did it, it's working, as you could see the main function of this API is to search so I inserted a query manually and tried to search but its not working their either.

Comment: Okey so your query works, that's good. Did the saving work with ``saveAndFlush``? So I can focus on trying to figure out what's wrong with the GET

Comment: Nope, It didn't work. It again gave a null output i.e {}

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with your code. It works perfectly fine with h2. You can find working code with in-memory database [here](https://github.com/spote87/stackoverflow-q72846625). So can you make sure there is data in your database with `firstName` or `lastName` as "Parthh"? If yes, can you share screenshot of your query with data?

Add employee request:
[image]

Get employee request and response:
[image]

Comment: I tried again, it is not able to fetch data from mysql, and also when I try to post JSON data, it is only accepting 'Id' & 'covid_status' rest all values are null.
Also how could I share screenshots? Edit the question?

Comment: @ErasableNinja yes, edit the question and add screenshot. Also are you able to reproduce this issue with h2 as well? Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes tried h2 but same issues. Also adding ss please check and let me know.

Comment: You said you are facing same issues with h2. Can you update your GitHub repository with reproducible h2 implementation? It is easier to debug and fix issue if we can reproduce it. I am sorry I am asking you to do lot of things but if we are able reproduce issue, we can fix it

Comment: Would be possible for you to connect with me on a meet? I know it's too much to ask for but there are terms which I don't understand here.

Comment: Sure, love to help. You can send me invite on shivaji.pote@gmail.com anytime after 8 PM CET